# Find this limit without using L'Hôpitale

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Can any give me a hint to solve this limit

$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{ln(x)}
$
I used L'Hôpitale rule and I found that the solution is *-$\frac{1}{2}$*
And I tried another ways like 
$
T=x-1$
$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{ln(t+1)-t}{tln(t+1)}
$
And I don't get any thing after that 
Any help would be very good 
 *Note: taylor series isn't available*
Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=e^x-1$ then you want to find (I changed the order here,  so I get the limit $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $-\frac{1}{2}$, sorry)

$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x(e^x-1)}$$

multiply by $$1=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$ and the problem simplifies to

$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$
Note that
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x}+x-1}{x^2}$$ thus

$$2L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x}+e^x-2}{x^2}=
\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1-e^{x}}{x}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\right)=(-1)(-1)=1$$

So $$L=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This (nice trick) assumes that the limit exists.

Comment: @did yeah, I was just waiting for somebody to ask that (they always do), the function is increasing as can easily be shown by algebra.

Comment: I see. So, the sign of $$\frac1{x(\log x)^2}-\frac1{x-1)^2}$$ is so obvious that no explanation about it is needed? :-) Not to mention that the function could be increasing on $x<1$ and on $x>1$ but have a jump at $1$... All in all, and trying to guess the OP's level of mathematical sophistication, I think I squarely disagree with your pedagogical choices here.

Comment: @did I dont care a jot about pedagogy. Why do you ? We are doing math here.

Comment: Interesting take. Anyway, where is the **mathematical** justification that the limits from the left and from the right exist and coincide? Without it, the answer is **mathematically** incomplete and falls into the most common **mathematical** trap about the subject. You want to "do maths"? Then do that properly!

Comment: Preserved for posterity (and because the more I read it, the more I like it): "I dont care a jot about pedagogy. Why do you ? We are doing math here. – Rene Schipperus 2 hours ago"